# Run function in index.js from script in public folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to run a script in my main index.js file from a script in the public folder. I do not know how to link the two.

I am trying to do this because I need to run file system operations on the server side. I have tried to link the script in the main HTML file, but when I try to run the function, it cannot be found.

my index file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require("fs");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('public/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'));

function test() {
  console.log("test");
}
```

my script in the public folder just has `test();`

my linking HTML

```html
 <script src="script.js"></script>
 <script src="../index.js"></script>
```

I am expecting the test function to run, and log 'test'. It does not, and i get no console logs or errors.

All code is available [on repl.it](https://repl.it/@LukeZeller/NBShell-NodeJS-Beta)

Comment: Where is your `test` function called?

Comment: @PrerakSola in script.js, a script also in the public folder.

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to achieve something, that you shouldn't do. Why don't you create an endpoint that takes care of the file operations on the server-side and use that endpoint from the client?

Comment: @dominik thank you, ill do some googling on how thats done

Comment: No - you cannot run a file in your node js script from another file which is suppose to run in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People say the best feature of Node.JS is the ability to use the same code on the client and the server. However it isn't *that* simple.

You can't just include code in your HTML outside of the public folder. If you want to call a function on the server side, you will need to do something like this:

```js
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  test() // will log on the server side
  res.send("All ok!");
});
```

And request that on the client side like so:

```js
fetch('/test').then(res => {
  console.log('got result from server!')
})
```

Essentially, you cannot just call functions on the server side - you have to talk to the server through HTTP. What you *can* do is create a shared folder with utility functions which you could include on both the client and server, but they couldn't be written with any reference to node modules unless you used a bundler (such as WebPack / RollUp).

Comment: thank you! how would i recieve the data i sent through res?

Comment: Check out the MDN guide on [using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) - res represents the response, but to get the body (i.e. the data) you'll need to use one of the mixins. Say the body is in json, you call `.json()` on the res, which returns another promise

Answer (score 0):

you are confused with client side java script and server side node js  file.
index.js is server side node js file. It has express link and runs like node index.js  now if you want to use a java script function inside node js application you can use this example.

http://techslides.com/client-side-javascript-to-node-js
rest this line   cannot be used  for a nodejs server side js file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run a function in your server script from another script which is running in the browser unless the function is set to be called via an end point. The server script and the browser script are not running in the same system so, they don't share the same execution context to call the functions in each other in a plain fashion.

Here is how you set the server function to be able to call from another system.

```
app.get('/runtest', (req, res) => {
  test();
  rest.status(200).send('Ok');
});
```

Now you can call this from your browser script via [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a script in public folder in `index.js` in server-side. Because index.js is a script running in a server. This can't be include script in `public` folder which runs in the client(web browser). To run `script.js` in public folder you can create a new file in server with same name scirpt.js.

**Script.js**

```js
module.exports = function test () {
  // do some stuff
};
```

And import in index.js.

**Index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// import test function from script.js file in here
const test = require('./script.js');
var fs = require("fs");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('public/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'));

// using it in here
test();
```

The `const test = require('./script.js');` using to import `function test` from script.js file and using it in the last line `test()`.